# How to filter out data when using same column from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find how many MED types have a child ORAL type that do NOT have a child IV type in the following table.

| ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | MED |
| 2 | 1 | ORAL |
| 3 | NULL | MED |
| 4 | 3 | ORAL |
| 5 | 3 | IV |
| 6 | NULL | MED |
| 7 | 6 | ORAL |
| 8 | NULL | MED |
| 9 | 8 | ORAL |
| 12 | NULL | MED |
| 13 | 12 | ORAL |
| 14 | 12 | IV |
| 15 | 12 | ORAL |

I can find a count of All MED types that have a child ORAL type AND a child IV type with the following.

```
select count(distinct(a.ID))
from Table1 a
join Table1 b
on a.ID = b.PARENT_ID
join Table1 c
on a.ID = c.PARENT_ID
where a.TYPE = 'MED' and b.TYPE = 'ORAL' and c.TYPE = 'IV'
```

But I can't figure out how to filter out the MEDs that only have type ORAL and NOT type IV. This is what I tried but it returns nothing. It should return a count of 3 (rows 1, 6, 8).

```
select count(distinct(a.ID))
from Table1 a
join Table1 b
on a.ID = b.PARENT_ID
where a.TYPE = 'MED' and b.TYPE = 'ORAL'
and not exists (
    select a.ID
    from Table1 a
    join Table1 b
    on a.ID = b.PARENT_ID
    join Table1 c
    on a.ID = c.PARENT_ID
    where a.TYPE = 'MED' and b.TYPE = 'ORAL' and c.TYPE = 'IV'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can solve the problem like this
We take all records by condition and exclude keys where IV is present

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
   AND t2.utype = 'ORAL'
 WHERE t1.utype = 'MED'
   AND t1.id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM table1 t3 WHERE t3.utype = 'IV')
```